# Add row with Jquery - Need to increment inputs names and onkeyup event caller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a bit new to JQuery and still trying to figure out how to add (clone) a table row at the end of the table and increment the `input name="code10"`, `onkeyup="recordTrans1(this.value)`", and this div (`<div class="txtHint3"></div>`) inside a table cell.

Essentially I just want those 3 things to increment by 1 (e.g : `name="code11"`, `onkeyup="recordTrans2(this.value)`", `<div class="txtHint4"></div>`, and so on...)

The code I have now is working perfectly to add or remove the table rows.

The problem I have is when I add a new table row, I don't see it in the "View source" of the page and the `name="codeX"`, `onkeyup`, and div is not incrementing.

I tried a few different ways and can't seem to figure it out so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I have to far :

```
<script>

jQuery.fn.addClone = function() {

return this.each(function() {

    // get row for cloningg
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var parent = {};

    // use tbody or table parent
    if ( $(row).parents('tbody').length>0) {
        parent = $(row).parents('tbody');
    } else {
        parent = $(row).parents('table');
    }

    // inject clone
    var copy = $(row).clone();
    $(copy).addClass('sadey');
    $(copy).addClass('isclone');
    $(parent).append( copy );

    // remove last td and replace with remove html
    $('.sadey').children('td:last').remove();
    $('.sadey').append('<td><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" onclick="$(this).killClone()">Retirer</button></td>');

    // increment all ids and names
    var id = ($('.isclone').length + 1);
    $('.sadey').find('*').each(function() {
        var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (typeof tempId != 'undefined' && tempId!='') {
            $(this).attr('id',tempId  + '_' +  id);
        }
        var tempName = $(this).attr('name');
        if (typeof tempName != 'undefined' && tempName!='') {
            $(this).attr('name',tempName + '_' + id);
        }
    });

    // remove active tag
    $('.sadey').removeClass('sadey');

});

};

// remove a row and re-index the clones
jQuery.fn.killClone = function() {

var row = $(this).parents('tr');
$(row).remove();

// re-index
var id = 2;
$('.isclone').each(function() {
    $(this).find('*').each(function() {

        var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (typeof tempId != 'undefined' && tempId!='') {
            tempId = tempId.split('_');
            $(this).attr('id',tempId[0]  + '_' +  id);
        }
        var tempName = $(this).attr('name');
        if (typeof tempName != 'undefined' && tempName!='') {
            tempName = tempName.split('_');
            $(this).attr('name',tempName[0]  + '_' +  id);
        }
    });
    id++;
 });
};

</script>
```

And here's the HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="FinancialDataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Code</th>
                <th style="width: 5%;">Qté</th>
                <th>Produit</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>



              <tr>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="code10" name="code16" class="form-control" onkeyup="recordTrans1(this.value)"   />
                </div>

                </td>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="qte16" class="form-control" value="1" />
                </div>

                </td>
                <div id="txtHint3">
                <td></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </div>

                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="$(this).addClone();">Ajouter un autre article</button></td>
              </tr>

                             </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: I have managed to increment the name="" and the id="" but I still need to find a way to incremenet(change) the event attribute to another Jquery function everytime it adds a new row.

Comment: Instead of viewing page source try clicking `inspect element` which will show the JQuery updates

Comment: Yes I have figured that out and now see that the values are incrementing. I would just need the part to increment/update event attribute function

Answer (score 0):

**You can not see the updated source code by**

`Right click -> View page source`

Browser loads the source code in a new Tab again when you click it. So,

**Instead of using it use Code Inspector**

`Right click -> Inspect element`

**To get onkeyup attribute updation, you can modify a part of your the code by this:**

```
$('.sadey').find('*').each(function() {
        var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (typeof tempId != 'undefined' && tempId!='') {
            $(this).attr('id',tempId  + '_' +  id);
            $(this).attr('onkeyup','recordTrans' +  id + "()");
        }
        var tempName = $(this).attr('name');
        if (typeof tempName != 'undefined' && tempName!='') {
            $(this).attr('name',tempName + '_' + id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I figured that out and I see the name="" and the id="" is incrementing.

Comment: I still need to figure out how to also increment the event attribute function and there is a div inside one of the td's that I should also increment the id of the div....Let me know if you can help me! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Plz compare the code mentioned in the edited ans with yours & modify. Do not forget to vote :)

Comment: It worked pretty well and I also figured out to duplicate and increment the div. Thank you so much!!!!